# Template rendered callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze, jquery-tabs

I'm using jquery tabs in my code. I need to call $('ul.tabs').tabs(); after once the HTML is rendered. But this is throwing error "Type : d[0] is undefined". The code which is used is below.

```
<template name="customersMapping">
    <div class="col s9 blue-grey lighten-5" id="side-right">
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12"> 
                      <ul class="tabs" id="usersMappingTab">
                       {{#each customerClientMapping}}
                          <li class="tab col s2"><a href="#{{_id}}_Tab">{{name}}</a></li>
                       {{/each}}
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    {{#each customerClientMapping}}
                        <div id="{{_id}}_Tab" class="col s12">
                            {{#each userChats ..}}
                                <div>{{name}}: {{message}}</div>
                            {{/each}}
                        </div>
                    {{/each}}
              </div>
           </div>
```

In client.js

```
Template.customersMapping.rendered = function() {
    if ($('#usersMappingTab').length > 0) {
                $('ul.tabs').tabs();
    }
};

Template.customersMapping.helpers({
    'customerClientMapping' : function() {
        return UserChatsMapping.find({cid : Meteor.userId()}, {sort: {time: -1}});
    },
    'userChats' : function() {
        return Messages.find({uid:this.uid}, {sort:{time: -1}});
    }
});
```

I think the jquery function is called before the HTML is rendered. Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: try `Meteor.setTimeout` and apply after 500 milliseconds or at the end of the template create helper which will apply tabs

Comment: this is an issue with the data behind the `customerClientMapping` helper. Keep in mind that initially all collections will be empty and only a fraction of a second later they will be filled with data from the server. You'll need to wait for that data to arrive before you can assume that the list is non-empty.

Comment: Did you try Template.customersMapping.onRendered ?
http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Template-onRendered

Comment: @Sasikanth Meteor.setTimeout worked but when data grows I feel need to increase timeout.

Comment: @mahdavipanah I tried  Template.customersMapping.rendered and onRendered also. It didn't worked.

Comment: Try this:  
    `Template.customersMapping.rendered = function() {  
        $( "#usersMappingTab" ).load(function() {  
             $('ul.tabs').tabs();  
         });  
     };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have divided into two template, one for managing subscriptions, and other for rendering tabs.

In the first template(customersMapping) we wait subscriptions to be ready.

When they are ready we can render our second template(tabs).

In tabs template's onRendered callback we can call jquery ui's tabs method without delaying the execution, because our data is already transferred to the client.

```
<head></head>

<body>
  {{> customersMapping}}
</body>

<template name="customersMapping">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        {{> tabs}}
    {{else}}
        loading...
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="tabs">
   <div id="tabs">
       <ul>
       {{#each customerClientMapping}}
           <li><a href="#{{_id}}_Tab">{{name}}</a></li>
       {{/each}}
       </ul>
       {{#each customerClientMapping}}
           <div id="{{_id}}_Tab" class="col s12">
           <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
          </div>
      {{/each}}
 </div>
```

```
UserChatsMapping = new Mongo.Collection("userChatsMapping");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.customersMapping.onCreated(function() {          
      this.subscribe("userChatsMapping");
  });

  Template.tabs.helpers({
     customerClientMapping: function () {
         return UserChatsMapping.find().fetch();
     }
  });

  Template.tabs.onRendered(function() {
      $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
}


// SERVER
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
    // put random data into collection
        if (UserChatsMapping.find().count() === 0) {
            _.each(_.range(10), function() {
                UserChatsMapping.insert({
                    name: faker.name.findName()
                });
            });
        }
 });

 Meteor.publish("userChatsMapping", function() {
     // simulate some delay
     Meteor._sleepForMs(2000);
     return UserChatsMapping.find();
 });
}
```

Comment: I'm facing one issue now. The tabs are not re sizing dynamically once it is loaded. Also if I remove all tabs and trying to add tabs dynamically the also not working.