# onRendered cannot find element in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, templates, meteor

I have a template

```
{{#if hasItems}}
  <ul id="myId">
    {{#each items}}
      {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{else}}
  <p>No items</p>
{{/if}}
```

and

```
Template.itemList.onRendered( function () {
  var el = this.find( '#myId' );
} );
```

but the element with `id="myId"` was never found because the template intially has no items, so the element `<ul id="myId">` does not exists when the template was rendered.

What can I do to make sure the element exists when rendered?

I guess I can either put `var el = this.find( '#myId' );` inside `Tracker.autorun` or make a nested template

```
<template name="hasItems">
  <ul id="myId">
    {{#each items}}
      {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

and include this template when `hasItems` is true and then use `onRendered` for `hasItems` instead of the outer template.

but isn't it a bit ugly hack?

Comment: how do you subscribe to the data? You can use `subscriptionsReady()` inside autorun to know when data is loaded.

Comment: IMHO the nested template solution is the way to go ;)

Comment: As @MarkUretsky said you have to wait for subscriptions to be ready. You can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470472/template-rendered-callback/33498046#33498046)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should do

**Templates**

```
<template name="itemList">
  {{#if hasItems}}
    {{> showItems }}
  {{else}}
    <p>No items</p>
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="showItems">
  <ul id="myId">
    {{#each items}}
      {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

**Render Handler**

```
Template.itemList.helpers({
  hasItems: function() { 
    // do you have items? 
  }
});

Template.showItems.onRendered(function (){
  var el = this.find( '#myId' );
});

Template.showItems.helpers({
  items: function() { 
    // return the items
  }
});
```